# JTable column Icon issue

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have added icon in the table first column; but when scroll the table, the icon is showing other columns as well.

Code:

```
private Object getColumnValueForPhysicalBOMHistory(BOMLinkMO value, int column) {
        switch (column) {
        case 0:
            // ProtomAbbreviation.CHANGE_ACTIVITY,
            String textvalue = "";
            Icon editicon = editIcon;
            if (uiViewModeState == UIViewModeState.PREVIEW && value.getDiffType() != ItemDiffType.NONE) {
                // +, -. /
                textvalue = value.getDiffType().toVisibleString();
                return new SimpleProtomTable.TextIconValue(textvalue, editicon);
            } else {
                textvalue = value.getTypeOfModification(deliveryDate);
                return new SimpleProtomTable.TextIconValue(textvalue, editicon);
            }
        case 1:
            // ProtomAbbreviation.BOM_CR_ID,
            if (value.getDTO().getCrId() != null && !"".equals(value.getDTO().getCrId())) {
                return value.gettest();
            } else {
                return "";
            }
```

Comment: Without more evidence, I'd say you're not resetting the cell renderer or it's value to exclude the icon

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and a [screenshot](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post).